# Why do we need to write initialiser for a class in Swift, but not for Struct

Tags: ios, swift

Swift provide Memberwise Initializers for `struct` Types. But when it comes to `class` we need to explicitly provide an `init()` by ourselves. I was trying to understand logic behind such a decision.

Sample,

```
struct SomeStruct {
    var someVar:Int
}
// Memberwise Initializers
let structInstance = SomeStruct(someVar:0)

class SomeClass {
    var someVar:Int
}

let classInstance = SomeClass()
```

`~~>`    ERROR at line 11, col 21: 'SomeClass' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
    let classInstance = SomeClass()

Answer (score 6):

The logic behind it could be because a `struct` is not subclassable, making it obvious that a complete initializer would be required, and as such it was made implicit by the language.

On the other hand, a `class` is subclassable, and as such you may want to design it so that it can only be initialized from subclasses, and as such an implicit initializer was not provided by the language.

Answer (score 2):

*(As pointed out by @Cœur below, this does not really answer the question, but might bring value to the context of it, so I'll leave it up)*

From [The Language Guide - Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html) [**emphasis mine**]:

> #### Definition syntax
>
> Here’s an example of a structure definition and a class definition:
>
> ```
> struct Resolution {
>     var width = 0
>     var height = 0
> }
> // ...
> ```
>
> ...
>
> #### Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types
>
> **All structures have an automatically-generated memberwise initializer**,
>   which you can use to initialize the member properties of new structure
>   instances. Initial values for the properties of the new instance can
>   be passed to the memberwise initializer by name:
>
> ```
> let vga = Resolution(width: 640, height: 480)
> ```
>
> Unlike structures, **class
>   instances do not receive a default memberwise initializer**.
>
> ...

Also worth mentioning that these are only available given that the strucutre do not define any of their own custom initializers; from the [Language Guide - Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

> #### Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types
>
> Structure types automatically receive a memberwise initializer **if they
>   do not define any of their own custom initializers**. Unlike a default
>   initializer, the structure receives a memberwise initializer even if
>   it has stored properties that do not have default values.
>
> ...

Comment: doesn't answer the question, which was a *why*. :)

Comment: @Cœur But it does answer the question. "All structures have an automatically-generated memberwise initializer".

Comment: @Cœur I agree, reading the question more carefully. Nonetheless, Hamish found an appropriate dupe target for this thread, so I believe it should be closed as a duplicate (and I also believe both answers here bring value to SO readers that might bounce into this Q&A, as well as further into its dupe target).

Comment: @Cœur Exactly, It doesn't answer 'WHY'. But your following explanation make sense. "On the other hand, a class is subclassable, and as such you may want to design it so that it can only be initialized from subclasses, and as such an implicit initializer was not provided by the language." 

Comment: @Jinto just wondering if your next question will be: _why, unlike class, struct is not subclassable?_ :joking:

Comment: @Jinto see also the [dupe target thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036202/why-doesnt-swift-provide-classes-memberwise-initializers), in which the accepted answer provides a quote from the main architect of Swift (which surely qualifies as a good _"why"_, w.r.t. design decision).